# WebGL image rendering bad quality

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, image-rendering

I have a problem with image rendering in WebGL: I have a canva, with a quad that takes the whole canvas, and a texture which is supposed to be mapped onto the whole quad (I have set the correct texture coordinates).

The image is a Uint8array containing RGB data (in this order) and the image is 1024*768 pixels. I have the correct buffer. Here is the link to the image.

[image: Original Image]

The problem is the following: when rendered into WebGL, my picture becomes blurry and fuzzy, even if I have a canva that is the size of the image. See the result below:

[image: Rendered via WebGL]

Now for the code: Here is the code I use to create the texture handle:

```
//texture
that.Texture = that.gl.createTexture();         
that.gl.bindTexture(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.Texture);                          

// Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
that.gl.texParameteri(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, that.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
that.gl.texParameteri(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, that.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
that.gl.texParameteri(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, that.gl.NEAREST);
that.gl.texParameteri(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, that.gl.NEAREST);
```

The data is loaded onto the texture as follows:

```
this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGB, this.m_iImageWidth, this.m_iImageHeight,
0, this.gl.RGB, this.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.m_aImage);
```

And finally, here is the fragment shader I use:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_image;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() 
{
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
```

I have tried a lot of options, from filtering to setting style option image-rendering pixelated, converting the image in RGBA and giving it RGBA values and the results is always the same crappy texture rendering. It looks like WebGL does not correctly interpolates the data even though the canvas is the exact same size as the texture.

Does any one have a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that the canvas width and height match the pixel display size. The display size is set via the style width and height.

Resolution is the number of pixels in the image. Display size is the amount of space that it occupies on the page. The two should match for the best results.

```
canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 1024; // set the canvas resolution
canvas.height = 784;

canvas.style.width = "1024px"; // set the display size.
canvas.style.height = "784px";
```

The display size if larger than the resolution will stretch the canvas out and cause the bluring

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However would'nt that change the canvas display area? If so, that is something I would like to avoid. Also, I don't understand why this has to be done. The texture rendered quality I obtain is way worse than the texture quality I would expect... I'll do a complete trial tomorrow when i'll be back to work. Thanks again!

Comment: @DerickThePoney You need to match the canvas resolution to the display size. That does not mean you need to change the display area, just the resolution of the canvas. You should expect high quality rendering, you are using `gl.NEAREST`. `gl.LINEAR` will improve the quality somewhat if the image does not match the canvas res or Mip map the image, or use the extension for TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT

Answer (score 4):

Let's try it.

```js
var vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position.xy * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
  v_texCoord = texcoord;
}
`;
var fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_image;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() 
{
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}`
;

var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var that = {
    gl: gl,
};
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "";
img.onload = function() {
  that.m_aImage = img;
  that.m_iImageWidth = img.width;
  that.m_iImageHeight = img.height;
  gl.canvas.width = img.width;
  gl.canvas.height = img.height;
  console.log("size: ", img.width, "x ", img.height);
  render.call(that);
}
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/ZCfccZh.png";

function render() {
  //texture
  that.Texture = that.gl.createTexture();         
  that.gl.bindTexture(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.Texture);                          

  // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
  that.gl.texParameteri(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, that.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  that.gl.texParameteri(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, that.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  that.gl.texParameteri(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, that.gl.NEAREST);
  that.gl.texParameteri(that.gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, that.gl.NEAREST);

  // upload the image directly.
  //  this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGB, this.gl.RGB, this.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
  // upload the image indirectly
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = this.m_iImageWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = this.m_iImageHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(this.m_aImage, 0, 0);
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.m_iImageWidth, this.m_iImageHeight);
  var numPixels = this.m_iImageWidth * this.m_iImageHeight;
  var pixels = new Uint8Array(numPixels * 3);
  var src = 0;
  var dst = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; ++i) {
    pixels[src++] = imageData.data[dst++];
    pixels[src++] = imageData.data[dst++];
    pixels[src++] = imageData.data[dst++];
    ++dst;
  }  
  
  this.m_aImage = pixels;
  this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGB, this.m_iImageWidth, this.m_iImageHeight, 0, this.gl.RGB, this.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.m_aImage);
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  
  var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  var bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Works for me. Although the image is apparently 800x600 not 1024x768. If your image isn't the same size as your canvas then you probably want to use `LINEAR` filtering instead of `NEAREST`.

Also, you can upload images directly rather than through an array buffer (same result but probably a lot smaller and faster and less memory)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! As @Blindman67 said, I believe the problem is the width and height of the canvas. As for the image size, I had to reduce it manually to get it onto stackoverflow :-) and for the image upload, I cannot use it. This image comes from a file, but most of the time images won't come from a bmp or a png but rather a camera. The images buffers are piped through a websocket to the website from a custom c++ server.

Comment: So did you try switching to `LINEAR` filtering?